# Javascript upload image to PHP base64_decode

Tags: javascript, php, base64

I have a javascript upload function that converts (and successfully displays) an uploaded image as a base64 code, like this:

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAARwCAIAAAD17XJXAAAAHGlET…ZrV0tK9FCERJTNmmAViRoe9QAawjnKAU5LlQhuSeIKVf8/0HbUB0ZqCkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

js code comes from a function I found on stackoverflow, code is here:

```
readImage: function(file) {

  var reader = new FileReader();
  var image  = new Image();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function(_file) {
    image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
    image.onload = function() {
      var w = this.width,
        h = this.height,
        t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
        n = file.name,
        s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';
      console.log(this.src)
      $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="'+ this.src +'"> '+w+'x'+h+' '+s+' '+t+' '+n+'<br>');
    };
    image.onerror= function() {
      alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
    };
  };

}
```

I am then posting that as a string to my PHP rest API, and doing this:

```
echo base64_decode('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAARwCAIAAAD17XJXAAAAHGlET…ZrV0tK9FCERJTNmmAViRoe9QAawjnKAU5LlQhuSeIKVf8/0HbUB0ZqCkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
exit;
```

but I just see false or blank space

Comment: 'data:image/png;base64,' is not b64 encoded - it is information about image file type. You must remove it before decoding.

Comment: $base64_string = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAARwCAIAAAD17XJXAAAAHGlET…ZrV0tK9FCERJTNmmAViRoe9QAawjnKAU5LlQhuSeIKVf8/0HbUB0ZqCkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
        echo $base64_string;
        exit;

comes out as: ‰PNG  IHDR€põírWiDMšÕÒÒ½!%3f˜bF‡½@°Žr€S’åB’x‚•ÏôµÑš‚“QS‘+˜

Comment: which is correct - that is decoded value.

Comment: The javascript displays this.src as data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAARwCAIAAAD17XJXAAAAHGlET…ZrV0tK9FCERJTNmmAViRoe9QAawjnKAU5LlQhuSeIKVf8/0HbUB0ZqCkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII= and the image looks like an image, not ‰PNG IHDR€põírWiDMšÕÒÒ½!%3f˜bF‡½@°Žr€S’åB’x‚•ÏôµÑš‚“QS‘+˜

Comment: if you want to display it you need to wrap it in image tag <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..." />

Comment: I see, how would I turn it into a PHP object to save it as a real file?

Comment: base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU... gives you binary representation of file. If you store it on disk it will be exact same as file you uploaded via js.